# React Rxjs with Falcor or Relay

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, relayjs, falcor

I have been playing with ReactiveX for a bit and really like the approach. I have also been following Relay and Falcor for a while and understand the advantages of declarative data fetching.

I have seen people integrating react, redux with falcor, but have not seen any attempts to integrate React, Rxjs with either Relay or Falcor.

So I wanted to write a simple todo example, but before that wanted to ask whether it is a sound combination at all. Are there compatible and whether some advantages of one approach will negatively affect advantages of others.

Also if anyone can share some resources on this topic please do :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries that I found: 
https://github.com/trxcllnt/reaxtor no React js though
https://github.com/FourSS/refar

UPDATE: there is an attempt by meteor developers to create their own version of relay using reactive graphql see [Apollo Project](http://www.apollostack.com/) They use observables for watch queries

Also there is a good library called [relate](https://github.com/relax/relate) which you can integrate with rxjs redux style state machine